# how to select the sibling in div by clicking anyone of anchor tag in the div

Tags: jquery

i am trying to create like/dislike function like stackoverflow's up vote and down vote function. Here is the sample code for what i have so far tried http://jsfiddle.net/Dd9Qa/3/ but i am not getting the desired result what i want is when i click like or dislike button in a particular div i should get the alert with the number in span field (further processing of increasing or decreasing of likes will be done here with ajax)

I want to get the value in span field when i click like/dislike button so that i can process it  please help how can i do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify which `span` you want to access.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Dd9Qa/9/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','a',function(){
        var a = $(this).closest('div').find('.votes').data('vote');
        alert(a);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `data()` instead of `attr()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('a').on('click',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       a = $(this).parent().parent().find('span').data('vote');
       alert(a);
      });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dd9Qa/11/

Comment: That will select all span elements.